# BottomNavigationView, icons spaced equally

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, material-ui, bottomnavigationview

I'm using BottomNavigationView with two items, however, on tablet or landscape, it pushed both icons to the center.
[image]

I'm trying to have equally spaced similarly to what material shows but without label:

[image]

Here is my code, does anyone know if there is an attribute that I could use to achieve this?

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/navigation_background"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/navigation_icon_color_selector"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

Comment: Add a dummy item in the menu between both items

Comment: it would still not be evenly spaced out

Answer (score 0):

Set this for each item, your items will all have even width

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

However if you want to place them evenly without expanding their width

Create empty views in between and add the above two lines instead like so

```
<View
android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"/>

<YourItem/>

<View
android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"/>

<YourItem/>

<View
android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"/>
```